# Does NSRegularExpression support partial case insensitive?

Tags: objective-c, regex, xcode, swift, nsregularexpression

As the title states, I wonder if NSRegularExpression in both Objective-c or Swift, support partial case insensitive search?

Namely, will the pattern recognize (?ismx)? If not, is there a brief reason for this inability?

I truly appreciate your explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [NSRegularExpression Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/index.html):

> **Table 2** Regular Expression Operators
>
> ...
>
> `(?ismwx-ismwx:...)`
>    Flag settings. Evaluate the parenthesized expression with the specified flags enabled or -disabled. ...
>
> `(?ismwx-ismwx)`
>   Flag settings. Change the flag settings. Changes apply to the portion of the pattern following the setting. For example, (?i) changes to a case insensitive match. ...

Example:

```
let pattern = "(?i)f(?-i)oo"
//Or: let pattern = "(?i:f)oo"
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: nil, error: nil)!

let string : NSString = "foo, Foo, fOO"
regex.enumerateMatchesInString(string, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, string.length)) {
    (result, flags, stop) -> Void in
    println(string.substringWithRange(result.range))
}
```

Output:

```
foo
Foo
```

The pattern matches "foo" and "Foo" because the "f" is matched case insensitive.
It does not match "fOO" because "oo" is matched case sensitive.

Comment: Is that capturing or not?

Comment: @Zaph: It does not (as far as I can see) introduce a new capture group. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Zaph: I have tested it: replacing `result.range` with `result.rangeAtIndex(1)` in the above example code throws an "out of range" exception, which means that there is no capture group in the pattern.

Comment: Thank you for detailed testing and explanation!