# Regular expression to get URL in string swift with Capitalized symbols

Tags: ios, regex, swift

I try to get URLs in text. So, before, I used such an expression:

```
let re = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "https?:\\/.*", options: nil, error: nil)!
```

But I had a problem when a user input URLs with Capitalized symbols (like `Http://Google.com`, it doesn't match it).

I tried:

```
let re = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(h|H)(t|T)(t|T)(p|P)s?:\\/.*", options: nil, error: nil)!
```

But nothing happened.

Comment: Probably because you still don't have a capital 's' ?

Comment: Use a case insensitive match instead? There is a [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823147/does-nsregularexpression-support-partial-case-insensitive) about doing it partially to retain performance.

Comment: I can understand why stack doesn't show urls. Sow the text is Http://Google.ru

Comment: You need to use an ignorecase flag, e.g. `(?i)https?:\\/.*`.

Comment: @nabiullinas: since it works for you, I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You turn off case sensitivity using an `i` inline flag in regex, see [Foundation Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/index.html) for more information on available regex features.

> `(?ismwx-ismwx)`
>   Flag settings. Change the flag settings. Changes apply to the portion of the pattern following the setting. For example, (?i) changes to a case insensitive match.The flags are defined in Flag Options.

**For readers:**

Matching an URL *inside* larger texts is already a [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url) [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url), but for this case, a [simple regex](http://www.rubular.com/r/H3GnoW81yz) like

```
(?i)https?://(?:www\\.)?\\S+(?:/|\\b)
```

will do as OP requires to match only the URLs that start with `http` or `https` or `HTTPs`, etc.

Comment: Does not work - 
Input - Test web http://google.com/hp new test okay bye
Output - http://google.com/hp new test okay bye

Comment: What do you mean? Could you post *visible* proof that it does not work? The point here is that `Http://Google.com` and `http://google.com` should be matched with `http://`. `(?i)` does turn case sensitivity off from the pattern.

Comment: Correct, OP needs to match only URLs containing `http` or `https`. This is the only requirement. My solution works for OP under current requirements. Please do not think them up.

Comment: Sorry about the downvote buddy. I can remove the downvote but SO wont let me do it unless you edit the answer again. The title of this question is a bit misleading. May be you could edit your answer to specify that? BTW I am in no way looking to make more points. Take it easy, buddy :-) Thanks

Comment: @Deb: I added a regex to match URLs that start with `http` or `https`. OP does not need to match others.

Answer (score 7):

### **Swift 4**

**1. Create String extension**

```
import Foundation

extension String {

    var isValidURL: Bool {
        guard !contains("..") else { return false }
    
        let head     = "((http|https)://)?([(w|W)]{3}+\\.)?"
        let tail     = "\\.+[A-Za-z]{2,3}+(\\.)?+(/(.)*)?"
        let urlRegEx = head+"+(.)+"+tail
    
        let urlTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx)

        return urlTest.evaluate(with: trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces))
    }

}
```

**2. Usage**

> ```
> "www.google.com".isValidURL
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this - http?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?

```
    let pattern = "http?://([-\\w\\.]+)+(:\\d+)?(/([\\w/_\\.]*(\\?\\S+)?)?)?"
    var matches = [String]()
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions(rawValue: 0))
        let nsstr = text as NSString
        let all = NSRange(location: 0, length: nsstr.length)
        regex.enumerateMatchesInString(text, options: NSMatchingOptions.init(rawValue: 0), range: all, usingBlock: { (result, flags, _) in
            matches.append(nsstr.substringWithRange(result!.range))
        })
    } catch {
        return [String]()
    }
    return matches
```

Comment: There is absolutely no need escaping  a dot inside a character class. Why use so many capturing groups? You are not using any.

Comment: Thanks for you comment, but did you check the test case I posted against your comment? Thanks

Comment: Tried it and found deb's answer can match exactly the url. stribizhev's answer will match from http till end of the line, which is not a legal url.

Answer (score 1):

Make an exension of string

```
extension String {
var isAlphanumeric: Bool {
    return rangeOfString( "^[wW]{3}+.[a-zA-Z]{3,}+.[a-z]{2,}", options: .RegularExpressionSearch) != nil
}
}
```

call using like this

```
"www.testsite.edu".isAlphanumeric  // true
"flsd.testsite.com".isAlphanumeric //false
```

Answer (score 0):

**My complex solution for Swift 5.x**

*ViewController:*

```
private func loadUrl(_ urlString: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.load(request)
}
```

*UISearchBarDelegate:*

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    guard let text = searchBar.text else { return }
    
    if !text.isUrl() {
        let finalUrl = String(format: "%@%@", "https://www.google.com/search?q=", text)
        loadUrl(finalUrl)
        return
    }
    
    if text.starts(with: "https://") || text.starts(with: "http://") {
        loadUrl(text)
        return
    }

    let finalUrl = String(format: "%@%@", "https://", text)
    loadUrl(finalUrl)
}
```

*String extension:*

```
extension String {

    func isUrl() -> Bool {
        guard !contains("..") else { return false }
        
        let regex = "((http|https)://)?([(w|W)]{3}+\\.)?+(.)+\\.+[A-Za-z]{2,3}+(\\.)?+(/(.)*)?"
        let urlTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", regex)
        
        return urlTest.evaluate(with: trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces))
    }

}
```